# Can I insert into a set, all the elements of a vector that matches a condition, in a single line of code

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdvector, stdset

I have a vector of elements. I want to populate a set using the elements of this vector that match a certain condition. Can I do this using one line, or in any way that is more concise than the below?

```
// given vector<int> v

set<int> s;
for (const int& i : v)
{
    if (/* some condition on i*/)
        s.insert(i);
}
```

For example, something along the line of:

```
// given vector<int> v

set<int> s;
s.insert(v.filter(/* lambda here*/));
```

It goes without saying that the v.filter method should return an iterator, not a separate populated vector, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [`std::inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) to insert the values into the set.  That looks like

```
std::copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::inserter(s, s.begin()), [](auto val) { return val == some_condition; });
```

Comment: You are 20 seconds faster, damn

Comment: @Slava Sorry, sloth mode was not active ;)

Comment: @DanielLangr It all depends on the type.  If it is not bigger than a pointer then AFAIK there is no advantage.  Of course of the object is big then a reference should be used.

Answer (score 4):

+1 for the `std::copy_if()` solution that, IMHO, is the natural solution for this problem.

Just for fun, I propose a different solution based on `std::for_each()`

```
std::set<int> s;

std::for_each(v.cbegin(), v.cend(),
              [&](int i) { if ( /* some condition */ ) s.insert(i); });
```

Comment: I don't see the gain of `for_each` now that we have for range.

Comment: @Jarod42 - not a gain at all, IMHO; it's just for fun (to show an alternative way to make the same thing) when the OP ask for a solution "in a single line of code" (but I suppose also the for range can be written and considered as a single line of code)

Answer (score 3):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), it would be

```
set<int> s = v | ranges::view::filter([](int e){ return cond(e); });
```

or simply (if `cond` already exist)

```
set<int> s = v | ranges::view::filter(cond);
```